# Pre save middleware on a schemaless collection not working? in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using a schema-less collection in mongoose

```
var User = new Schema({}, {
    strict: false,
});
```

I wanted to add/modify its properties before saving

```
User.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.some = 'thing';
    console.log(this.some) // => undefined
    next();
});
```

But this isn't working..

Comment: How do you call `.save`?

Comment: @liadmat What do you mean, the ["pre-save" middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)? It's called automatically

Comment: Of course, I wanted to make sure you're simply calling `user.save` with an existing user instance. Are you saying that `console.log(this.some)` prints `undefined` immediately after `this.some = 'thing'`? That is weird

Comment: @liadmat yeah exactly, it is. Although if I define the `some` property in the schema (i.e. not schema-less anymore) then it works. So it's not working only when it's schema-less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties not defined in the schema need to be accessed and set with `get` and `set` methods

```
this.set('some', 'thing'); // inside a middeware or a method
user.set('some', 'thing');
```

```
user.get('some'); //=> 'thing'
```